# Fastest cell iteration method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that, in practice, may have up to 2000 rows and 100 columns. I want to iterate through all of the cells and, depending on the nature of the underlying data in the cell, add the contents to a list. The code currently looks like this:

```
for (var columnIndex = 1; columnIndex < edgv.ColumnCount; columnIndex++)
{
    for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < edgv.RowCount; rowIndex++)
    {
        var currentValue = edgv[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value as ISomeInterface;
        if (currentValue != null && (currentValue.GetType().Equals(typeof(SomeClass).FullName)) 
            && (((SomeClass)currentValue).Attribute != null))
        {
            values.Add(currentValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works for smaller grids, but seems to bog down (if not stall out completely) when ColumnCount and RowCount start getting large. I'm wondering if changing the for loops to foreach loops might help, and I'm open to other ideas.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A ForEach is still a loop.  Don't guess at the bottle neck, try testing for it.  How fast does it run if you comment out your currentValue code?

Comment: I think you should spin up a prototype and test it yourself.  It's good programming karma.

Comment: This seems odd to me `currentValue.GetType().Equals(typeof(SomeClass).FullName)`.  Why not just `currentValue.GetType() == typeof(SomeClass)` or `currentValue is SomeClass`, or better yet use `as SomeClass` instead and you'll only need `if(currentValue != null && currentValue.Attribute != null)`

Comment: you could save some time by checking the `ValueType` property of the column and at least seeing it is assignable from `SomeClass` before you iterate through all the rows. Unfortunately access to internal data binding mechanisms is very limited in datagridview.

Comment: Runing the code against the datasource may be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The first step when improving performance of an existing process should usually be profiling. A profiler would tell you what piece of code takes the most amount of time, letting you know which piece needs to be optimized. A lot of time the bottleneck is where you least expect it, and without a profiler you might be wasting a lot of time on optimizing code which will give you close to zero practical performance improvement.

And now, I'll ignore what I've said in the previous paragraph to give a few suggestions:

1. You didn't share the code of where you create the `values` collection. Assuming it's a `List`, it has a constructor which gets a capacity parameter. This can be very important for performance. If you use the empty constructor, the default capacity is 5, which can be disastrous to performance in your scenario if you insert a lot of values to the collection.
   The reason for that is that list is internally implemented as an array of 'capacity' length, and whenever you insert an item above the length, it will create a new array with twice the length (which will now be the new capacity), and copy all the items from the old array to the new array.
   That copying process hurts performance. Also having to allocate new arrays all the time (and dropping the old arrays) will cause the GC to run amoc, and can also cause fragmentation in your memory, all those can be potential bottlenecks in your code.
   So you should choose an appropriate capacity when creating your list. You should choose the capacity based on your estimation of how many items will get into the list in the most common scenario.
   If, for example, you expect to usually insert almost all of your cells, you can call: `values = new List<SomeClass>(edgv.ColumnCount * edgv.RowCount);`
2. It's been said in the comments, but in each cell iteration you cast to `ISomeInterface` and then cast to `SomeClass`. As you don't really use `ISomeInterface` this is redundant. Just casting to `SomeClass` should be enough and might give you a performance boost.

   ```
       for (var columnIndex = 1; columnIndex < edgv.ColumnCount; columnIndex++)
       {
           for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < edgv.RowCount; rowIndex++)
           {
               var currentValue = edgv[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value as SomeClass;
               if (currentValue != null && currentValue.Attribute != null)
               {
                   values.Add(currentValue);
               }
           }
       }
   ```
3. Also been said in the comments, you might not need to iterate all the cells. Usually in grids, the type is the same for each column. If that's true in your case as well, then you can check the first cell in each column and based on its type, you can avoid checking the rest of the cells in that column.

   ```
       for (var columnIndex = 1; columnIndex < edgv.ColumnCount; columnIndex++)
       {
           for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < edgv.RowCount; rowIndex++)
           {
               var currentValue = edgv[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value as SomeClass;
               if (currentValue == null) break; //Skipping the check for this column
               if (currentValue.Attribute != null)
               {
                   values.Add(currentValue);
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: `values` is a `List<ISomeInterface>`, hence the initial cast. Most of what's going on is basically bulletproofing, though I find myself thinking that expanding the default capacity (as you suggested) may help.

Comment: Yes, but `SomeClass` inherits from `ISomeInterface` and you only care about `SomeClass` so the initial cast is still redundant. No need for bulletproffing since if `SomeClass` does not inherit from `ISomeInterface` it won't compile.